# Auto Layout constraint is not maintained when changing the height of the view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am fairly new to iOS app design. I have a container view (let's say **conView**) and a Label (let's say **nameLabel**) on a storyboard ViewController. I have set the top space constraint for **nameLabel** to be 20 point below **conView**. Now, when I changed the height for **conView** programmatically, the top space constraint for **nameLabel** is not maintained properly. I have used this code to change the height.

```
conView.frame.size.height = 200
```

What am I missing here? What will be the correct way to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the frame of a view breaks the layout constraints and forces the view to change the dimensions or position. What you have to do is update the constant of the constraint instead of changing the frame of the container view.

Let's say you have a constraint defining the height of the container view. Bind the constraint to the view controller(constHeight)

```
constHeight.constant = 200
```

If you do not have a height constraint defined for container view, update the available constraints to achieve the height you need.

This will update the height constraint. now we have to tell it that the constraints have been changed and it should update the layouts.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Bind the constraint to the view controller(constHeight) - how to do this exactly?

Comment: @anik_s, you have to bind the UI element to the view controller as an `IBOutlet`